# Is three.js better with react.js?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Is three.js better with react.js (in terms of performance and scalability)? I can't understand how are they supposed to interact.
(I'm just a beginner with three.js and I don't know React.js)
Also, is it worth to use react.js with three.js for a static website with 3D graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-three-fiber is the wrapper for using three.js with react.js. I have built some stuff with vanilla three.js and react but I will say the pain of mounting and unmounting a renderer based on the component is a big pain, and three-fiber manages that really well for you.

It really depends on what your goal is for the static site, is it your portfolio? If so then you may want to build it out in react with three-fiber so that you can talk about using relevant libraries. If your goal is web graphics then I would say yes three.js is your best bet.